# How to use wire model to link images on edit form in livewire

Tags: laravel-8, laravel-livewire

I have a form that is working well to update and insert images to database, my problem in my edit form I want the file selected to be linked with the path in the database but I can't figure it out.

Here is my code
In livewire class file I have

```
  $photo1a = 'photo1_'.time().$this->photo1->getClientOriginalName();
  $uploadphoto1 = $this->photo1->storeAs('public/vehicle',$photo1a);
  $photo2a = 'photo2_'.time().$this->photo2->getClientOriginalName();
  $uploadphoto2 = $this->photo1->storeAs('public/vehicle',$photo2a);
```

In the livewire blade file I have

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6">
        <label>Upload Front 1</label>
    <input type="file" wire:model="photo1" accept="image/*">
       <a href="{{asset('storage/vehicle/'.$photo1)}}" target="blank">{{$photo1}}</a>
    

    <span class="text-danger">@error('photo1'){{ $message }}@enderror</span>
     </div>
    <div class="col-md-6">
    <label>Upload Front 2</label>
    <input type="file" wire:model="photo2" accept="image/*">
      <a href="{{asset('storage/vehicle/'.$photo2)}}" target="blank">{{$photo2}}</a>
    <span class="text-danger">@error('photo2'){{ $message }}@enderror</span>
       </div>
</div>
```

My query

```
 DB::table('valuations')
                ->updateOrInsert(
                 ['val_id' => $num],[
                    "photo1"=>$photo1a,
                    "photo2"=>$photo2a
                      ]);// this works well
```

My problem is I have to select all images again then update. Any solution to this?

Answer (score 0):

instead of :

```
$photo1a = 'photo1_'.time().$this->photo1->getClientOriginalName();
  $uploadphoto1 = $this->photo1->storeAs('public/vehicle',$photo1a);
  $photo2a = 'photo2_'.time().$this->photo2->getClientOriginalName();
  $uploadphoto2 = $this->photo1->storeAs('public/vehicle',$photo2a);
```

use:

```
 $photo1a = 'photo1_'.time().'.'.$this->photo1->extension();
  $uploadphoto1 = $this->photo1->storeAs('public/vehicle',$photo1a);
  $photo2a = 'photo2_'.time().'.'.$this->photo2->extension();
  $uploadphoto2 = $this->photo2->storeAs('public/vehicle',$photo2a);
```